# Export settings for audiobooks

Tags: premiere, youtube

Suppose I'm making an audiobook with a simple JPG image as the only visual content and a single MP3 track as the only audio. What settings can I use to ensure that:

**A) The picture is still sharp, ie, the image remains at full resolution.**

**B) The audio is undistorted, native resolution (VBR 320).**

**C) The video is as small as possible.**

I'm aware that I can use multiple encoding passes to decrease filesize, but how can I tweak frame rate, video resolution, etc to simply show this 490KB image with the ~550MB of audio at the smallest total file size for streaming?

I'm working in Windows with Adobe Premiere, but open to other suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your audiobook is audio only, and there is only a single image associated with it, I would simply distribute it as audio with the image.

If you want to upload to YouTube or another streaming distribution site, use the preset meant for YouTube, or specify what site.

For a technical answer to your question assuming you're using H.264 or H.265; make the keyframe distance as long as possible, use 2 pass encoding, and use the native resolution and frame rate of your distribution medium.